# How to know when a Hangouts on Air/YouTube Broadcast is Live?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I'm building a webinar plugin using Hangouts On Air, the video is embedded on my site and registration of participants is build on another platform (A CRM).

I need to know when the webinar goes Live so I register whoever is viewing it as a participant (displaying an alert when it's live would be enough).

Also it would be useful to know if the webinar has ended, I'm not sure which API I should use, the Google+ API, a Hangouts API a YouTube Live Streaming API etc. and I haven't been able to do it with the Hangouts API (I think it doesn't work for the embed).

How can this be done?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497300/embed-youtube-live-streaming-automatically/24498117

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gapi.hangout.onair.onDisplayedParticipantInBroadcastChanged.add` method to register callbacks. For example:

```
gapi.hangout.onair.onDisplayedParticipantInBroadcastChanged.add(function(broadcastingChangedEvent) {
  if (broadcastingChangedEvent.isBroadcasting) {
    alert("Start broadcasting!");
  }
});
```

Here's the [document](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair#gapi.hangout.onair.onBroadcastingChanged).