# Embed YouTube Live Streaming Automatically

Tags: php, web, youtube-api

How to embed an YouTube live streaming automatically in an webpage using php?

Something like querying the video at https://youtube.com/user/USERID/live when a transmission is on air?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with using [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method by setting type=video and eventType=live

Here is another [PHP search code sample](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/search.php) that will get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much! It needs also to set channelId=CHANNELID, which is not the user id (username) but that ID that appears on bar when one opens the channel at YouTube. For the example on API's 'search->list' page to work one need to be not OAUTHed.

Answer (score 4):

I am the author of the OP. I wrote this PHP class, maybe it will be useful for some so I'll link here:

https://github.com/iacchus/youtube-live-embed

It allows one to query a channel and embed the Live Streaming if there is one. May take some seconds or even minutes to YouTube API response to show the live streaming after the streaming is On Air.

Comment: Thank youkind sir! I've been looking sooo long for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it easily by using below iframe code:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNEL_ID
```

You may have a look this site: [streambd.co](http://streambd.co) for your better understanding